# Table not updated when I save data from modal

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I'm using react.js and bootstrap 5, I'm confused how to add data from modal to the table, please help me figure it out, I'm newbie and want to learn react.js,  thanks before!

Modal

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Button, Form, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import "../../style/TambahDataSupplierModal.css";

const TambahDataSupplierModal = ({ show, handleClose, addSupplier }) => {
  const [selectedTanggal, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [selectedKategori, setSelectedKategori] = useState("");
  const [selectedStatus, setSelectedStatus] = useState("");
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    tanggalMasuk: "",
    nama: "",
    noFaktur: "",
    kontak: "",
    alamat: "",
    kategori: "",
    status: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    const newData = {
      tanggalMasuk: selectedTanggal,
      nama: formData.nama,
      noFaktur: formData.noFaktur,
      kontak: formData.kontak,
      alamat: formData.alamat,
      kategori: selectedKategori,
      status: formData.status,
    };

    addSupplier(newData);
    handleClose();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Data Supplier</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formTanggal">
              <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                Tanggal Masuk
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={8}>
                <DatePicker
                  todayButton="Hari ini"
                  placeholderText="Tanggal..."
                  selected={selectedTanggal}
                  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
                  dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                  maxDate={new Date()}
                  showMonthDropdown
                  showYearDropdown
                  dropdownMode="select"
                  isClearable
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formNama">
              <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                Nama Supplier
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={8}>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  name="nama"
                  value={formData.nama}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  placeholder="Nama Supplier"
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formNoFaktur">
              <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                No. Faktur
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={8}>
                <Form.Control
                  type="noFaktur"
                  placeholder="No. Faktur"
                  name="noFaktur"
                  value={formData.noFaktur}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formKontak">
              <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                Kontak
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={8}>
                <Form.Control
                  type="kontak"
                  placeholder="Kontak"
                  name="kontak"
                  value={formData.kontak}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formAlamat">
              <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                Alamat
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={8}>
                <Form.Control
                  type="alamat"
                  placeholder="Alamat"
                  name="alamat"
                  value={formData.alamat}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formKategori">
              <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                Kategori
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={8}>
                <Form.Check
                  type="radio"
                  label="Peralatan Medis"
                  value="Peralatan Medis"
                  checked={selectedKategori === "Peralatan Medis"}
                  onChange={(event) => setSelectedKategori(event.target.value)}
                />
                <Form.Check
                  type="radio"
                  label="Obat"
                  value="Obat"
                  checked={selectedKategori === "Obat"}
                  onChange={(event) => setSelectedKategori(event.target.value)}
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formStatus">
              <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                Status
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={8}>
                <Form.Check
                  type="radio"
                  label="Aktif"
                  value="Aktif"
                  checked={selectedStatus === "Aktif"}
                  onChange={(event) => setSelectedStatus(event.target.value)}
                />
                <Form.Check
                  type="radio"
                  label="Non Aktif"
                  value="Nonaktif"
                  checked={selectedStatus === "Nonaktif"}
                  onChange={(event) => setSelectedStatus(event.target.value)}
                />
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button id="closeButton" onClick={handleClose}>
            Tutup
          </Button>
          <Button id="saveButton" onClick={handleSave}>
            Simpan
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default TambahDataSupplierModal;
```

Table

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import "react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css";
import ToolkitProvider, {
  Search,
} from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit/dist/react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit.min";
import CetakButton from "../buttons/CetakButton";
import EditButton from "../buttons/EditButton";
import DeleteButton from "../buttons/DeleteButton";
import "../../style/TableSupplier.css";
import "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator/dist/react-bootstrap-table2-paginator.min.css";

const generateRandomData = (count) => {
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    const item = {
      id: i,
      tanggalMasuk: "2023-07-15",
      nama: "Supplier " + i,
      noFaktur: "F0010" + i,
      kontak: "0898765432" + i,
      alamat: "Jl. Supplier No." + i,
      kategori: "Tipe" + i,
      status: "aktif",
      aksi: "edit",
    };
    data.push(item);
  }
  return data;
};
const TableSupplier = () => {
  const [suppliers, setSuppliers] = useState(generateRandomData(52));

  const addSupplier = (newSupplier) => {
    setSuppliers([...suppliers, newSupplier]);
  };
  const { SearchBar } = Search;
  const columns = [
    {
      dataField: "id",
      text: "No",
      sort: true,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      type: Number,
    },
    {
      dataField: "tanggalMasuk",
      text: (
        <span>
          Tanggal Masuk <br /> Supplier
        </span>
      ),
      sort: true,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      type: Date,
    },
    {
      dataField: "nama",
      text: "Supplier",
      sort: true,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
    },
    {
      dataField: "noFaktur",
      text: "No. Faktur",
      sort: true,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
    },
    {
      dataField: "kontak",
      text: "Kontak",
      sort: true,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
    },
    {
      dataField: "alamat",
      text: "Alamat",
      sort: true,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
    },
    {
      dataField: "kategori",
      text: "Kategori",
      sort: true,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
    },
    {
      dataField: "status",
      text: "Status",
      sort: true,
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      type: "bool",
      formatter: (cell, row) => (
        <span className={`status ${cell ? "aktif" : "nonaktif"}`}>
          {cell ? "Aktif" : "Nonaktif"}
        </span>
      ),
    },
    {
      dataField: "aksi",
      text: "Aksi",
      headerAlign: "center",
      align: "center",
      sort: false,
      csvExport: false,
      formatter: (cell, row) => (
        <div className="editDeleteWrapper">
          <EditButton></EditButton>

          <DeleteButton></DeleteButton>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];

  // Configure the pagination options

  const customTotal = (from, to, size) => (
    <span className="react-bootstrap-table-pagination-total">
      Showing {from} to {to} of {size} Results
    </span>
  );

  const paginationOptions = {
    // alwaysShowAllBtns: true, // Always show next and previous button
    // withFirstAndLast: false, // Hide the going to First and Last page button
    // hideSizePerPage: true, // Hide the sizePerPage dropdown always
    // hidePageListOnlyOnePage: true, // Hide the pagination list when only one page
    firstPageText: "First",
    prePageText: "Back",
    nextPageText: "Next",
    lastPageText: "Last",
    nextPageTitle: "First page",
    prePageTitle: "Pre page",
    firstPageTitle: "Next page",
    lastPageTitle: "Last page",
    showTotal: true,
    paginationTotalRenderer: customTotal,
    disablePageTitle: true,
    sizePerPage: 10,
    sizePerPageList: [
      {
        text: "10",
        value: 10,
      },
      {
        text: "25",
        value: 25,
      },
      {
        text: "50",
        value: 50,
      },
      {
        text: "All",
        value: suppliers.length,
      },
    ],
  };

  // Define the initial sorting
  const defaultSorted = [
    {
      dataField: "id",
      order: "asc", // or "desc" for descending order
    },
  ];

  const MyExportCSV = (props) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
      props.onExport();
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <CetakButton text="Export CSV" onClick={handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ToolkitProvider
      keyField="id"
      data={suppliers}
      columns={columns}
      exportCSV
      search
    >
      {(props) => (
        <div className="mainTableWrapper">
          <div className="barButtonWrapper">
            <div className="cetakButtonWrapper">
              <MyExportCSV {...props.csvProps} />
            </div>
            <div className="searchBarWrapper">
              <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <BootstrapTable
            {...props.baseProps}
            keyField="id"
            data={suppliers}
            columns={columns}
            defaultSorted={defaultSorted}
            pagination={paginationFactory(paginationOptions)}
            {...props.baseProps}
            bootstrap4
            striped
            hover
            condensed
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </ToolkitProvider>
  );
};

export default TableSupplier;
```

when I save data from modal form,the table not updated like its static table, I'm expecting the table updated when I add the data.

Comment: From where you are calling the modal?

Comment: I've updated my code below, thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

I call modal from my mainpage.js and its contain the table too
here is some of my code.

```
<div className="tambahDataButtonWrapper">
            <TambahDataButton
              text="Tambah Data Supplier"
              onClick={handleOpenModal}
            />

            <TambahDataSupplierModal
              show={showModal}
              handleClose={handleCloseModal}
              addSupplier={(addSupplier) => {
                // Lakukan sesuatu dengan data supplier baru
                console.log("Supplier baru:", addSupplier);
              }}
            />
          </div>
```